# Doctrine expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got ','

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-7

On my Ubuntu Server in my virtual machine, this query (see the method after the Entity's code) work perfectly but on my online server, Doctrine says this error :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 92: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got ','

This the code in Profile entity :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;

/**
 * Description of  Profile
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProfileRepository")
 * @SWG\Definition(@SWG\Xml(name="profile"))
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $lastName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastName", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string $firstName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var Company $company;
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var User $user
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var ProfileVariety $profileVariety
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProfileVariety")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profileVariety_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $profileVariety;
}
```

The code in the Profile Repository :

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Description of ProfileRepository
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Repository
 */
class ProfileRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByEmail($email)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('profileByUserEmail')
            ->select('p')
            ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Profile', 'p')
            ->join('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = p.user')
            ->andWhere('u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter(':email', $email)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Could you explain me the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should join `p.user` directly:

```php
->select('p')
->from('AppBundle\Entity\Profile', 'p')
->join('p.user', 'u')
->where('u.email = :email')
```

If you join another entity class explicitly, Doctrine expects you to specify the JOIN condition with a `WITH` keyword, and not in the WHERE condition:

```php
->select('p')
->from('AppBundle\Entity\Profile', 'p')
->join('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u', 'WITH', 'u = p.user')
->where('u.email = :email')
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the first exaple is valid when you have relation defined as in `Profile` you have `user` defined. The second one is for case when the relation is not defined in entities.

Comment: @Łukasz Indeed!